# Sorting HashMap based integer array in the value

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to sort a HashMap based on second element in the integer array.

Examples: Consider I am having a HashMap like below

```
<"Alex",[12,18]> 

<"Bob",[13,45]>

<"Ball",[13,45]>

<"Candy",[1,2]>
```

then the output should be :

```
Ball Bob Alex Candy
```

Can we do it using Lambda functions?

Comment: You could put the HashMap keys into a list, and have your sort's compare function look up the desired comparison values from the appropriate HashMap entries.

Comment: A `HashMap<K,V>` can't be sorted, as it is an associative container whose order is not guaranteed. Furthermore you're trying to sort by value (and not by key) which is not expected by `Map<K,V>` in general. The only way to do this in a simple way is to collect `Map.Entry<K,V>` elements as a list and sort the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption 1: int array is already sorted.

In Java using Lambda's

```
HashMap<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("Alex", new int[] {12,18});
    map.put("Bob", new int[] {13,45});
    map.put("Ball", new int[] {13,45});
    map.put("Candy", new int[] {1,2});

    Map<String, int[]> result = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue((int[] a, int[] b) ->
                    IntStream.of(b).sum() - IntStream.of(a).sum())
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));

    System.out.println(result);
```

Bonus - In Groovy:

```
HashMap<String, List> map = new HashMap<String, List>()

map.put("Alex", [12,18])
map.put("Bob", [13,45])
map.put("Ball", [13,45])
map.put("Candy", [1,2])

println map.sort {a,b -> b.value.sum() <=> a.value.sum()}
```